# CURTIME() gets server time not timezone specified in php.ini

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

I've created a php.ini containing this info

```
date.timezone="Asia/Riyadh"
```

but when inserting CURTIME() to the database it inserts the server time not the defined timezone in php so I've tried something else. Using this code

```
$nowTime = date('g:i a');
```

and insert the variable. It gets the right date but no am or pm. Any help please?

Comment: What data type is your column in the DB?

Comment: `CURTIME()` is a mysql function. It couldn't care less about your PHP settings.

Comment: it's TIME type isn't it correct?

Comment: @jqbeginner That's fine but it's 24 hour, so there's no am/pm. Try `date('H:i:s')` instead

Comment: @SmokeyPHP it worked you can add it as an answer so i can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the TIME format which works in 24 hour format, you therefore need to use the 24 hour syntax in your [date function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), as below:

```
$nowTime = date('H:i:s');
```